# Assign to selection in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe and I want to create a new column, that is computed differently for different groups of rows. Here is a quick example:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'foo': list('aaade'), 'bar': range(5)}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

The dataframe looks like this:

```
     bar foo
0    0   a
1    1   a
2    2   a
3    3   d
4    4   e
```

Now I am adding a new column and try to assign some values to selected rows:

```
df['xyz'] = 0
df.loc[(df['foo'] == 'a'), 'xyz'] = df.loc[(df['foo'] == 'a')].apply(lambda x: x['bar'] * 2, axis=1)
```

The dataframe has not changed. What I would expect is the dataframe to look like this:

```
     bar foo  xyz
0    0   a    0
1    1   a    2
2    2   a    4
3    3   d    0
4    4   e    0
```

In my real-world problem, the 'xyz' column is also computated for the other rows, but using a different function. In fact, I am also using different columns for the computation. So my questions:

1. Why does the assignment in the above example not work?
2. Is it neccessary to do `df.loc[(df['foo'] == 'a')` twice (as I am doing it now)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're changing a copy of df (a boolean mask of the DataFrame is a copy, see [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy)).
Another way to achieve the desired result is as follows:

```
In [11]: df.apply(lambda row: (row['bar']*2 if row['foo'] == 'a' else row['xyz']), axis=1)
Out[11]:
0    0
1    2
2    4
3    0
4    0
dtype: int64

In [12]: df['xyz'] = df.apply(lambda row: (row['bar']*2 if row['foo'] == 'a' else row['xyz']), axis=1)

In [13]: df
Out[13]:
   bar foo  xyz
0    0   a    0
1    1   a    2
2    2   a    4
3    3   d    0
4    4   e    0
```

Perhaps a neater way is just to:

```
In [21]: 2 * (df1.bar) * (df1.foo == 'a')
Out[21]:
0    0
1    2
2    4
3    0
4    0
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Yes, Jeff, writing something more to the docs is on my todo list. :)

Comment: and I didn't even comment :)

Comment: thanks for your quick answer. This does exactly what I want. Is it possible to chain those if else calls?

Comment: @uuazed what do you mean by chain? If the logic gets complicated I recommend pulling it out to a function (and applying that function).

Comment: by chaining I mean something like: "if ... elif ... elif ... else". Now I just used two steps, which works fine.

Comment: I am also using a function to keep the code somewhat readable. Does using a function have a performance impact?

Comment: @uuazed yes it'll have a performance hit, as will using a lambda, if you could try rewriting your logic as similar to [21] above... it'll definitely be more efficient.

Comment: but using something similar to [21] would result in doing "2 * df.bar" (which is something more complex in my case), for each row of the dataframe. using the if else approach, the calculation is only done for the rows that matter. right?

Comment: @uuazed it's a trick to do the if/else, since False in 0 and True is 1 (sorry not sure why I use `df.bar` over `df['bar']`)